# Как обойти тег basefont?

Tags: html

Являясь новичком в HTML, работая с самоучителем, наткнулся на такой вопрос. В IE <basefont size=6> работает прекрасно. Смотрю через Google Chrome - шрифт без изменений. Помогите, как вопрос решить.

Comment: Вам сюда: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-size

Answer (score 3):

эммм....какого года эта книга?
все изменения стиля отображения теперь принято в `css` прописывать...

Answer (score 1):

Это устаревший тег, не используйте его, используйте CSS!

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/basefont  Смотри ни какой браузер кроме ехплорер не поддерживают ее.